# In my browser clear cookies session also destroyed why?

Tags: php, session, cookies

Clear cookies in my browser session also destroyed why? I using PHP Scripts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The basic idea behind SESSION is that, When you create or call session_start() method your server generate a session id and store it on server memory. Also the server create a cookie on your client machine that cookie contains an id that is related to your server side session id. When you call session_destroy() method server delete that id on server side but the client side cookie doesn't. That is why your session id still shown. You can also check by cache and cookie clearing. When you clear cookie your session will destroyed.